# what is more accurate seen or shown, please help.

Tags: grammar

What's more accurate
Seen or shown?

- what i feel right now is seen on this picture.
- what i feel right now is shown on this picture.

Comment: A third idiomatic possibility to consider would be “What I feel right now is **captured** in this picture.”

Answer (score 1):

**"What I feel right now is shown *'in'* this picture"** is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you word it. If you want to use the word seen, the sentence should be:

> What I feel right now can be seen in this picture.

For the word shown, the sentence should be:

> What I feel right now is shown in this picture.